# Преобразовать строку в дату

Tags: java, дата, преобразование

У меня есть строка формата "12 фев 21, 07:36", мне необходимо ее преобразовать в дату, я пробую так

```
private static Date transformToDate(String date) throws ParseException {
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yy, HH:mm");
    return dateFormat.parse(date);
}
```

Получаю ParseException Unparseable date: "12 фев 21, 07:36", пробовал так же убирать время с помощью split и переводить только "12 фев 21", но получал такой же эксепшин, может кто-нибудь помочь пожалуйста ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В принципе все правильно делаете, только язык не учли -

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    String date= "12 фев 21, 07:36";
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yy, HH:mm", new Locale("ru"));
    System.out.println(dateFormat.parse(date)); 
}
```

Comment: Получаю тот же самое: Unparseable date (

Comment: @nPaBllla, new Locale("ru") не забыли поставить? У меня работает и выдает результат - "Fri Feb 12 07:36:00 EET 2021"

Comment: Нет, все поставил, в idea у меня не работает, я попробовал еще на онлайн компиляторах и там в 50% срабатывает, не могу понять от чего это зависит

Comment: @nPaBllla, какая версия java у вас? В 8-й работает, в других надо смотреть.

Comment: У меня четырнадцатая

Comment: Попробовал в 8ой, работает, спасибо !