# Не преобразуется строка в дату с сокращенным месяцем в русской локали

Tags: java, парсер, datetime, locale

Есть строка вида "7-дек-2019 22:33:17.345". При попытке перевести в дату получаю ошибку:

> java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "7-???-2019 22:33:17.345"

Мой код следующий:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS", new Locale("ru"));

String dateInString = "7-дек-2019 22:33:17.345";
Date date = formatter.parse(dateInString);
System.out.println(date.getMonth());
```

Когда я пишу месяц полностью "декабрь" все работает. Для английской локали тоже работает с сокращением JAN напримерю Как парсить даты с сокращением в месяце? А также можно ли сделать чтобы парсило и так и так, т.е. "дек" и "декабрь" чтобы обрабатывалось одинаково правильно. У меня данные по разному приходят.

Comment: Какую версию джавы используете ? [У меня была похожая проблема с датой](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1244510/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%b2-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83) она решилась сменой версии джавы на 8ую

Comment: 11-я. ну это не дело если только в 8-й)

Answer (score 1):

Используйте класс `DateFormatSymbols`, в экземпляр которого передаете массив сокращенных названий месяцев, сохраняя порядок следования.

```
DateFormatSymbols symbols = new DateFormatSymbols(new Locale("ru"));
String[] shortestMonths = new String[] {"янв", "фев", "мар", "апр", "май", "июн", "июл", "авг", "сен", "окт", "ноя", "дек"};
symbols.setShortMonths(shortestMonths);

SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS", symbols);

String dateInString = "7-дек-2019 22:33:17.345";
Date date = formatter.parse(dateInString);
System.out.println(date.getMonth() + 1);
```

Код набросал быстро и не тестировал, но в теории должно все заработать.

В конце нужно добавить +1, потому что месяцы в классе `Calendar` начинаются с 0